# CSS positioning relative over fixed/absolute

Tags: html, css, positioning

Apologies if I appear quite "noobish" with CSS.  I've been trying to set the following...

```
#0 {
 width: 100%;
 height: y;
 border: 1px solid black;
}   
#a {
 position: fixed;
 float left;
 width: x;
 height: y;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#b {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: x;
 height: y;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}

/* HTML */
<div id="0">Some div...</div>
<div id="a">Another div</div>
<div id="b">Final div...</div>
```

For some reason, if I attempt to position #b below #a, #b will appear ontop of #a unless I declare its position as either static or absolute, but will then be required to manually position the top/left properties, and this doesn't display properly for all browsers either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Have got it fixed now! (had to declare html, body:( width: 95%;)) Thanks for all the advice guys!

Comment: may be you have learn about positioning. for more check these links http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ , http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/ , http://blog.themeforest.net/general/15-css-tricks-that-must-be-learned/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a couple of fixes: #0 needs to be named something else, because IDs cannot start with a number. You're also missing a : in the float property for #a. Not sure what's with the 'x' and 'y' for the height/width, either - I assume those are just examples?

Fixed and Absolute elements are out of the document flow. That is, they don't take up space as far as normal positioned elements.

Therefore, the fixed element will have the relative one over it in your example, as you found because they can inhabit the same x-y space. If you had it as absolute, top:0; left: 0, the same thing would happen.

Next, you had one as a float (almost), so let's consider that float changes all of that positioning. Floats are 'special' in the way they are laid out. They are in the flow, but will be as far up and in the float direction as possible. If they're too wide to fit next to other floated content on that line, they go to the next line.

You could do

```
<style>
 #a
  {
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:black;
  }
  #b
  {
  clear:left;
  height:100px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:green;
  }
 </style>
 <div id='a'>aaaaa aaa</div>
 <div id='b'>bbb bbb</div>
```

'Clear' means an element will appear beneath preceding elements that are floated. #b will be on the next line, underneath #a. You could also make #a have a big margin on the right, or be wide enough to fill whatever container and not leave room for #b, to make #b be beneath #a instead of next to it.

Comment: IDs can absolutely start with a number in HTML5.

Comment: @Matt Ball okay... guess we'd better tell him to declare a doctype?

Comment: Apologies for the incoherence, but this didn't work for my intentions - I was trying to create an empty box with #a, appended outside #zero with #b displayed next to #a, almost as if it's a bar attached to a box.

Comment: @user784446 Sorry as well, I didn't really see #0 in the HTML before. Still confused about what you mean but I'm glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your `width: x` and `height: y` syntax is correct, and your `#a` float property is missing a colon. Also, IDs can't start with numbers, so `#0` should be changed to something else. Here is the code that makes everything work right. You had to get rid of your fixed and relative positioning.
CSS:

```
#zero {
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
}   
#a {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#b {
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="zero">Some div...</div>
<div id="a">Another div</div>
<div id="b">Final div...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the syntax used was merely to emphasize an example.  Anyway, this didn't work for my intentions - I was trying to create an empty box with #a, appended outside #zero with #b displaying next to #a.