# Why do relatively positioned divs cover fixed divs?

Tags: css, html, layout, css-position

Why do relatively positioned divs cover fixed positioned divs?

Here is an example:

## HTML (with relatively fixed div wrapping content)

```
<div id="topheading">
    Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="centerpage">
        <div class="contentbox1">
            Test
        </div>
        <div class="contentbox1">
            Test 2
        </div>
        <div class="contentbox1">
            Test 3
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#topheading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 58px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(194, 194, 194, .5);
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.centerpage {
    width: 99%;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 62px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.contentbox1 {
    float: left;
    width: 99%;
    background: #448;
    min-height: 200px;
    border: solid black 2px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RampagingMiner/x64Jf/)

The fixed positioned div becomes covered by the relatively positioned div when you scroll down; How come?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS positioning relative over fixed/absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314193/css-positioning-relative-over-fixed-absolute)

Comment: Add `z-index:1` to `#topheader`'s CSS properties :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because the z-index of the divs is implicitly set by the order in which they are parsed. That is to say,

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="centerpage">
        <div class="contentbox1">
            Test
        </div>
        <div class="contentbox1">
            Test 2
        </div>
        <div class="contentbox1">
            Test 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="topheading">
    Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example
</div>
```

Seems to solve your problem.

EDIT: Though, as others have stated, the more expressive way to solve this would be to use z-index.

```
#topheading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 58px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(194, 194, 194, .5);
    z-index:1;
}
```